# Bootstrap Push and Pull with 3 column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to re-arrange column in small screen column which are in following sequence 1,2,3 should show as 3,1,2 in small screen.

It works fine with two but i am not sure how to make it work with three column with the following structure

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green;">3. This should be first one on small screen</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjZJRG

I tried few but it breaks the design not sure if it will work with three column.

Comment: If you are using flex, then you can manage order with media query

Comment: @SurajKhanal, i have to manage with same structure if flex works without breaking the design then it is worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

As you are working with BS3, you can use the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">2</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 pull-right" style="background-color:green;">3. This should be first one on small screen</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `pull-right` bootstrap css or custome css can you give more details

Comment: @Learning If you are using BS 3.x its available in it.

Comment: I tried it is not working for me for some reason that is why i asked

Comment: @Learning Which Bootstrap version you are working with?

Comment: @Learning I've modified your demo. Check this [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjMxdL)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap 4 then you can use flex class to manage that. In this case you can use order-*.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-6 order-sm-2" style="background-color:lavender;">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 order-sm-1" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 order-sm-0" style="background-color:green;">3. This should be first one on small screen</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one show even same or large screen for medium & large i want sequence 1,2,3

Comment: This is not working while you resize browser window but works when you reload page to target device size.